# pip install puts tensorflow in the wrong kernel

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pip, kernel, conda

I am running a Jupyter notebook using the conda kernel 3.11.5, but when I try to do `pip install tensorflow` it installs to a different kernel (Python 3.7.9) which was the one I originally had in my computer. I already upgraded the pip and it lets me install tensorflow, it just installs it in the wrong kernel.

How can I change the install location?

I think I have to use `pip install -t (location)` but I am unsure how to find the exact location.

I also tried this `python-3.11 -m pip install tensorflow` using the box below as reference, but it says python-3.11 is not recognized

```
# The system default python:
$ python -m pip install fish

# A virtualenv's python:
$ .env/bin/python -m pip install fish

# A specific version of python:
$ python-3.6 -m pip install fish
```

(Source: [Dealing with multiple Python versions and PIP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip))